# How to receive logs from multiple filebeats running on different machine(ec2) to one logstash instance?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat, elk

i have 2 filebeats running on different machine(Ex: A & B) and filebeat is also configured to send logstash machine but logstash is not receiving the data even though I have added the private IP of those machines.

so i have 2 logstash .conf file to receive from 2 different filebeats.

My conf file looks like this ->

### A.conf

input{
beat{
port:""
host:"private-ip-m1"
}
}

### B.conf

input{
beat{
port:""
host:"private-ip-m2"
}
}

after I run logstash it is unable to connect. it says Error: Cannot assign requested address.

Can anyone tell me is there any other way to this ?